# Changing Entity Framework Entity Class Without Changing Schema

Tags: entity-framework

I have an application already in production using EF 5.0. I'm about to start on the next major revision. But before I do that, I'm trying to clean up a lot of my existing code.

One thing I want to change, is use a different class for one of my table entities. The new class is functionally identical to the previous. The only real difference is the name. E.g. ReceiptEntity will become Receipt.

This is to help simplify things, and stick to a simple naming convention.

However, EF Migrations are wanting to drop-recreate the table. This is not an option because the application is already in production. And I cannot allow for any data-loss.

Is there any way to change the Entity type without recreating the table that would make EF happy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by altering the generated migration.

The generated migration tried to create a table(one that already existed), then immediately drop it(which would of resulted in the data-loss).

I deleted all of the generated code, and simply 'Update-Database'ed an empty migration, and this solved the problem for me.